# Firebase Firestore get only one field from document

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Is there the ability with Firebase Firestore to only get one field from a document?

```
public String getUserName(){
    DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("cities").document(mAuth.getUid());
    docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                if (document != null) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot data: " + task.getResult().getData());
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "No such document");
                }
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "get failed with ", task.getException());
            }
        }
    });

    return name;
}
```

I use the above code to retrieve a Map with all data in it but would like to know if there is functionality to just call a field name and retrieve that fields data?

My Firestore database is below. I would like to be able to retrieve the Name field only.

[image]

Comment: The marked duplicate is for Swift, but the same applies for all client platforms.

Comment: Thanks for that. Just to confirm I understand what the switft post states. I should actually be creating all my users as collections and having documents as the fields?

Example
Collection: User 1. Document: Name. Field: Matt
Collection: User 1. Document: Email. Field: test@test.com

Comment: Not sure what you're asking here.  It doesn't seem to be related to your original question.  If you have a question about data modeling, that would be a different question.

Comment: What i am asking is if i should be storing my fields shown in the above screen shot as documents?

Comment: Sure, if it works for your queries.  Data modeling for nosql databases is entirely dependent on how you intend to query for that data.  It's up to you.